# Preserving formatting in a BERT-tokenized string

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

If I tokenize some string

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

tokens = t.tokenize("I don't think the situation is quite as cut-and-dried as that - you should ask him directly.")
```

Then `t.convert_tokens_to_string(tokens)` will return `"I don ' t think the situation is quite as cut - and - dried as that - you should ask him directly."`.

Is there some way to preserve the original formatting in the "untokenized" text? Perhaps by using a different tokenizer? I am doing masked word replacement, but only on whole words, and the BERT tokenizer is quite good for this, as opposed to e.g. the GPT-2 tokenizer which does preserve formatting better, but doesn't allow single word manipulation quite as easily.